# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Byte[]' type to a nullable 'System.Byte' type is not valid

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<byte>> GetPersonalPicture3(Nullable<System.Guid> contactId)
    {
        var contactIdParameter = contactId.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("ContactId", contactId) :
            new ObjectParameter("ContactId", typeof(System.Guid));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<byte>>("GetPersonalPicture3", contactIdParameter);
    }
```

in the bottom Code, I Faced this error "The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Byte[]' type to a nullable 'System.Byte' type is not valid."

```
byte x = DBPSO.GetPersonalPicture3(ProfileID).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0000;
```

in addition, I've tested this Code too

```
var x = DBPSO.GetPersonalPicture3(ProfileID).Select(B => B.Value).ToArray();

string binaryPic = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture on the db is probably a varbinary so an array of byte and not a single byte.
Try this:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<byte[]> GetPersonalPicture3(Nullable<System.Guid> contactId)
{
    var contactIdParameter = contactId.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("ContactId", contactId) :
        new ObjectParameter("ContactId", typeof(System.Guid));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<byte[]>("GetPersonalPicture3", contactIdParameter);
}
```